# Creating using-like commands in C#

Tags: c#

I know that C# does not currently support this, so this is more of a meta-C# question. I have been thinking of what changes would be required in the language to allow us to create our own commands like `while` or `using`. I could create a method accepting an `Action`, like `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, but then I would need parentheses around the curly braces and the syntax would not look the same.

Would this essentially amount to allowing us to apply parameters outside of the parentheses?

i.e.

```
public void MyUsing (IDisposable disposable) Action body
{
    try
    {
        body();
    }
    finally
    {
        disposable.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Commands like `for`, `switch` and `if` would be even more complicated to create because of their syntax.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Are you suggesting a language feature? If so, [here's where you should be](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/topics/5998/c-language-design) (but you should be more clear there, too).

Comment: He's not exactly proposing a language feature. More wanting a discussion on how to implement it in the compiler / language. I still don't think it belongs here though

Comment: None of those are "commands". They are statements in the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to take a look at the Roslyn project (which is essentially an opensource C# compiler written in C#!)
They also have demos of how easy it is to add language features.

https://roslyn.codeplex.com/

However, take note that it is unlikely for your changes to be accepted unless you are working in the C# team. If you want to have code generated for you, you could take a look at PostSharp, it isn't the same thing as you were suggesting, but it might suit you situation anyway.

http://www.postsharp.net/

PostSharp allows you to mark methods, properties, classes etc. with Attributes which will then trigger user defined code generation functions which will run after the initial compile process. It helps in situations where you don't want to copy paste the same code pattern over and over again.